# sort array with 2 conditions, one numeric and the other based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have been looking for a way to sort an array based on 2 conditions:

**First**: Sort it based on another array, one being like this:
This is the json file to read:

```js
let versiones = ['versionZ', 'versionJ', 'versionA', 'versionK', 'versionC']
```

*If it is not present in the versions array, put them last*

**Second**: Then order it based on its priority present within the elements.

*Note: The priority will always exist, it may be that in some cases the key: version does not exist or is shown as null.*

Here it would be the array that I want to order without complete success:

```json
    [
        { "name": "Juan", "priority": 10, "version": "versionM" },
        { "name": "Manuel", "priority": 5, "version": "versionA" },
        { "name": "Carlos", "priority": 20, "version": "versionJ" },
        { "name": "Raul", "priority": 12, "version": "versionC" }     
    ]
```

Comment: Any feedback on my answer ?

Comment: a.sort(function(e1, e2){
 let x = versiones.indexOf(e1.version);
 let y = versiones.indexOf(e2.version);
 
 if (x == -1 && y >= 0) {
  return 1;
 }
 if (y == -1 && x >= 0) {
  return -1;
 }

 if ( x >= 0 && y >= 0 ) {
  return x - y;
 }

 return e1.priority - e2.priority;
})

Comment: when sorting by version, it doesn't have to be in alphabetical order, it has to be in the same order that the versions array shows @kmoser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let LevelOnePriority = ["Z", "J", "A", "K", "C"];

let obj = [
    { name: "Juan", levelTwoPriority: 10, version: "M", },
    { name: "Manuel", levelTwoPriority: 5, version: "L", },
    { name: "Carlos", levelTwoPriority: 20, version: "Z", },
    { name: "Raul", levelTwoPriority: 12, version: "C", },
    { name: "Park22", levelTwoPriority: 7, version: "A", },
    { name: "City25", levelTwoPriority: 6, version: "A", },
];

obj.sort(function(a, b) {
  // "a" is in the highestPriorityArray and "b" isn't
  if (LevelOnePriority.includes(a.version) && !LevelOnePriority.includes(b.version)) {
    return -1;
  }
  // "b" is in the highestPriorityArray and "a" isn't
  if (!LevelOnePriority.includes(a.version) && LevelOnePriority.includes(b.version)) {
    return +1;
  }

  // Both "a" and "b" are in the highestPriorityArray
  if (LevelOnePriority.includes(a.version) && LevelOnePriority.includes(b.version)) {
    // "a" and "b" aren't in the same version
    if (LevelOnePriority.indexOf(a.version) !== LevelOnePriority.indexOf(b.version)) {
      // 
      return LevelOnePriority.indexOf(a.version) - LevelOnePriority.indexOf(b.version);
    }
  }

  return a.levelTwoPriority - b.levelTwoPriority;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: what I try is that it first shows all the versionZ and these arrange them in order of priority.
Then those of versionJ... and so on
The main priority is the version

Comment: @JoseManuel Check the update. you can see that `Carlos` comes first.

Comment: when sorting by version, it doesn't have to be in alphabetical order, it has to be in the same order that the versions array shows

Comment: @JoseManuel It is the case, I have `{ name: "Carlos", priority: 20, version: "versionZ", },` appearing before `{ name: "City25", priority: 6, version: "versionA", },`

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, there was a small error that generated bad data to the api

Comment: That's great to know :D. good luck. I'll edit variables names to make the solution more generic

Comment: Upvoted for the useful comments

Comment: @kmoser The solution you provided in the comments makes me feel so noob XD. I'm trying to find a shorter solution using math.

Comment: @medilies I'm not sure how much simpler it can get than what you already have. The if/then logic is what makes this as complex as it is, and I don't see math helping there.

Comment: @kmoser here is what I'm trying https://jsfiddle.net/q7f82b46/10/

Comment: @medilies Why the +2?

Comment: @kmoser because not found in array gives -1 that what I turn it to +1. Then the order of factors becomes [NotFound:1, Last:2, ...... First:Max]